# Excel, calculate hh:mm time difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I have 2 cells (A1, A2), formatted as `[h]:mm` for example:

###### Example 1

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `40:00` |
| 2 | `30:00` |
| 3 | Here should display `-10:00` |

In cell A3, I want the `hours:minutes` difference between the 2 cells, in the same format (`[h]:mm`). In the above example, in A3 it should display `-10:00`.

###### Example 2

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `40:00` |
| 2 | `45:00` |
| 3 | Here should display `5:00` |

I have tried `=TEXT(A1-A2, "[h]:mm")` in A3 which *works* when A2 is smaller than A1, but in example 1 it will display `10:00` instead of `-10:00` and in example 2, it will error.

How could I achieve that calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-` with the text format to have a "negative" time.

```
=TEXT(A1-A2,"-[h]:mm")
```

For both cases, use:

```
=IF(A1>A2,TEXT(A1-A2,"-[h]:mm"),A2-A1)
```